# WPF - set the ItemsSource of List View based on some condition

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, itemssource

Is it possible to set the ItemsSource of a list view based on Some condition.
   I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FirstTypeOfSource}"  .....>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style >
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Category}" Value="All">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="SecondTypeOfCategory"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
   </ListView>
```

Can someone help to figure out the solution ?

Comment: "Didn't work" - What is the error?

Comment: It says the property "ItemsSource" cannot be found

Comment: You might have to specify the `TargetType` for the `Style`:  <Style TargetType="ListView" > ...

Comment: And you are setting the style for `ItemsContainer`, but that is not where `ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add a name to a ListView.

```
<ListView x:Name="someName" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstTypeOfSource}" .....>
```

Use element name to find desired DependencyProperty:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Category}" Value="All">
    <Setter TargetName="someName" Property="ItemsSource" Value="SecondTypeOfCategory"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FirstTypeOfSource}">
        <ListView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ListView">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Category}" Value="All">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SecondTypeOfCategory}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Style>
    </ListView>
```