# Datatrigger to change a ListView ItemsSource not firing

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding

I am trying to change the `ItemsSource` Property of a `ListView`, depending on if a collection contains elements or is null.

The `ListView` currently looks like this:

```
    <Control.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="GridFiles_MouseDoubleClick" />
        </Style>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DirectoryFiles" Source="{Binding Path=CurrentDirectory.Files}"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DirectorySubDirs" Source="{Binding Path=CurrentDirectory.SubDirectories}"/>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="CombinedCollection">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource DirectorySubDirs}}" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource DirectoryFiles}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </Control.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="gridFiles" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFileGridItem}"
              ItemsSource="{StaticResource CombinedCollection}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Extension" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Extension}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Checksum" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Checksum}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
<Grid>
```

In my viewmodel there is an `IEnumerable<FileNodeViewModel>` property called SearchResults which is filled with results after performing a search, otherwise its null.
If I manually set the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` property to `{Binding SearchResults}` the search results are displayed as intended, so I am sure that the data is correctly formated and available to the `Listview`.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039056/wpf-set-the-itemssource-of-list-view-based-on-some-condition) I found a similar question and appended the xaml code:

```
    <Control.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="GridFiles_MouseDoubleClick" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SearchResults}" Value="All">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SearchResults}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DirectoryFiles" Source="{Binding Path=CurrentDirectory.Files}"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DirectorySubDirs" Source="{Binding Path=CurrentDirectory.SubDirectories}"/>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="CombinedCollection">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource DirectorySubDirs}}" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource DirectoryFiles}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </Control.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="gridFiles" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFileGridItem}"
          ItemsSource="{StaticResource CombinedCollection}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Extension" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Extension}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Checksum" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Checksum}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
<Grid>
```

However, nothing changes. No matter if the SearchResults property is `null` or not, the `ListView` always displays the combined collection. I also tried to create a boolan property to indicate if the second collection should be displayed or not, with the same result:

```
<Style TargetType="ListView">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowSearchResults}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SearchResults}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Does anybody know how what I should do to correctly change the `ItemsSource` property?

Comment: `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SearchResults}" Value="All">` will of course not work (unless perhaps SearchResults returns the string "All"). However, a `public boolean ShowSearchResults` property with change notification should work.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Turns out that the basic setup was fine, but it's not possible to overwrite explicit properties via styles. I explained it in detail in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to bind to `SearchResults` only if it's not null, or else you wan to bind to `CombinedCollection`? You could then use a `DataTrigger` with a value of `{x:Null}`:

```
<ListView x:Name="gridFiles" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFileGridItem}">
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SearchResults}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SearchResults}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{StaticResource CombinedCollection}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Extension" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Extension}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Checksum" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Checksum}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Make sure that you only set the `ItemsSource` property in the `Style` `Setter`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that somebody posted an answer when I added answer myself. Your take at it seems much cleaner, so I'll update my own code and post an update.

Comment: Alright, setting the datatrigger on Searchresults with a check on null doesn't seem to trigger for me. I ended up using a using an additional ShowSearchResults variable which gives me the added benefit of having more control over when exactly the data is displayed if the processing takes longer in the background.

Comment: It should trigger provided that the binding can be resolved and that the property actually returns a null reference.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some trial and error I found the issue. Everything was pretty much set up correctly, but I was not aware that styles can only append properties to an element, not replace existing ones.

To test this, I created a new ListView:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2"
          ItemsSource="{StaticResource CombinedCollection}"
          Foreground="Blue">
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowSearchResults}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The data was displayed correctly, with blue foreground color. If I changed ShowSearchResults to True, nothing happened, the color still was blue. So I removed the foreground property:

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2"
          ItemsSource="{StaticResource CombinedCollection}">
```

I retried the test, and suddenly the ListView items would turn red. Knowing this, I removed the explicit data source from the ListView definition and used two data triggers instead.

For reference, here is the working markup. Thanks a lot to mm8 for providing some great input about the formatting!

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="gridFiles" Margin="2"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFileGridItem}">
        <ListView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ListView">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{StaticResource CombinedCollection}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowSearchResults}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SearchResults}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Style>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Extension" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Extension}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Checksum" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Checksum}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```